# How do I split metrics per app within an app service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

How do I split metrics in an app service plan based on app within the service plan? For example, I'd like to determine which apps within the plan are on average consuming the most CPU, Memory, etc to then use that to determine which apps to move to a different service plan that I can scale independently?

Comment: are you using app insights ?

Comment: Yes, using app insights